# How can I put text into css3

Tags: css

I'm wondering if it's possible to have certain pieces of 'static' text in the css3 instead of in the HTML, just like one can also have 'background-image' in css3 ?

I have searched on Google but cannot seem to find any reference to this.

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: Short answer: no.  Longer: CSS is styling information.  HTML is content information.  static text is content, thus it is part of the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply, no, not like a `background-image`.

You may use `:before`/`:after` selectors with the `content` property, but that wouldn't work like a background image, it would place the text either before or after the element.

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YkerN/ and support table: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent (IE8+; no problems in other browsers)

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo selectors like :before and :after can specify a content property, which can be text.

```
p:before {
  content: "this will appear before all paragraph content";
}
```